# jQuery serialize from datatables to PHP array without ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, serialization, datatables

I have a table using Datatables. I have a setup pretty much like [this link](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/form.html) in the fact that I have form fields in the table and that they are submitted. I don't want to use ajax, I want to use the submit button.

This is part of my code:

```
$('#form').submit( function() {
    var sData = $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).serialize ();

    console.log(sData);
    $('#form-values').val(sData);

} );
```

So I'm taking the serialized data and I'm putting it in a hidden input box with the id #form-values. Once I submit, In the server side I can get the serialized data with `$_POST['form-values']` but of course... the data is serialized... I would want that data in an array so I can analyze it and insert some of them in a database.

I tried doing `unserialize($_POST['form-values'])` but it gives me the error `Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1098 bytes in...`

My serialized data looks like:

```
comments%5B56%5D=&comments%5B35%5D=&comments%5B12%5D=&comments%5B32%5D=
```

But I would want it to be:

```
Array ( [comments] => Array ( [56] => [35] => [12] => [32] =>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get just the atributes from a URL using [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Once you have that you can use [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to convert them to variables, it works with multidimensional arrays too!

```
    $str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";

    parse_str($str, $output);
    echo $output['first'];  // value
    echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
    echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
```

Comment: I really wouldn't want to pass the values through the URL. Would only do it if that's the only option

Comment: does it really matter where they came from? take it from the post param and it should be the same.

Comment: Yeah.. my bad, after I re read the answer I understood better

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$params = array();
parse_str($_GET, $params);
```

Comment: Warning: parse_str() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: `$_GET` should be `$_POST['form-values']` i would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use [parseJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) jQuery function?

Comment: How would that help? he doesn't have any json to parse!

Comment: jQuery selector $() return an object that can be nicely parsed.

Comment: Right, with JSON.stringify, not parseJSON. jquery doesn't have a built-in method for turning an object into json.